# Pyplot combine two subplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to have two plots in one figure. I am stuck on this for a while now and I don't have any idea why it wouldn't work like I want it to. I have two functions, which return similar axes. The data comes from a csv file, where I get the frequency (y-axis) according to the size of specific objects (x-axis). I expect to have one figure displaying the plots on top of each other. However my plot only contains the legend to axs[1] and the data also only contains axs[1].

My code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

axs[0].plot(ax=return_some_ax())
axs[1].plot(ax=return_similar_ax())

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

I hope that you can help me out :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in general.  You can substitute your functions in place of x and y in here if they return a list of those values:

```
x_data = list(range(10))
y = [x**2 for x in x_data]
y1 = [x+5 for x in x_data]


fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(x_data, y, label = "quadratic", color = 'red')
ax2.plot(x_data, y1, label = "linear", color = 'blue')

ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image]

Here is the same code using two functions:

```
def function1(x):
    return x**2
def function2(x):
    return x+5

x_data = list(range(10))

fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(x_data, [function1(x) for x in x_data], label = "quadratic", color = 'red')
ax2.plot(x_data, [function2(x) for x in x_data], label = "linear", color = 'blue')

ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```